# proper simple declatation to iterate prepared struct array c without knowing number of elements

Tags: c, arrays, loops, struct, iteration

I have been looking through questions on how to iterate an array of structs containing mixed types of data fields, only to come with complicated answers. I'm looking for something rather simple.

My program retrieves IP addresses from linux IPtables along with status as to whether they are accepted or denied. The first fragment of the program is as follows:

```
iptstat* ips=malloc(100000);
memset(ips,0,99999);
// custom function is called here that properly fills up iptstat structure with data.
iptstat* p=ips;int sz=sizeof(iptstat);
```

The first fragment has no problems after running tests. Now the second fragment gives me difficulty because I'm unable to see the results of the data.

When I try to iterate a struct via:

```
while(p != '\0'){
printf("IP %s stat %d\n",p->IP,p->stat);
p+=sz; 
}
```

I receive on the screen:

```
IP  stat 0
IP  stat 0
IP  stat 0
...
IP  stat 0
Segmentation fault
```

I instead expected only two entries showing in the form of:

```
IP xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx stat x
```

where xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx is an actual IP address and x is either 1 or 2.

I then proceeded to change the problem fragment of my code to this in hopes that I can run a loop until I see a null pointer:

```
while(*p){
printf("IP %s stat %d\n",p->IP,p->stat);
p+=sz; 
}
```

The compiler reports:

```
./test.c: In function 'main':
./test.c:78: error: used struct type value where scalar is required
```

and line 78 is the while loop I'm struggling with.

Is there a simple answer to this, or am I going to have to go with a rather complicated answer involving a for-loop?

Comment: `x is either 1 or 2.`....um, why?

Comment: You *really* need to keep track of the size yourself! Also, `p` is a pointer to `ipstat` which is not a character, don't compare arbitrary pointers to characters.

Comment: The only way to solve it in a way similar to what you do now, is to add a special sentinel structure last, containing values that can't be in a normal structure, and check for that. Then you could check `p->some_member != SOME_ILLEGAL_VALUE`

Comment: x is 1 or 2 for the statuses accept and deny respectively. I use numbers to save on memory space.

Comment: I was trying to figure out how to compare the struct to a null or is that even possible?

Comment: Only a pointer can be `NULL`, and if you want to compare a pointer to `NULL` then compare it to `NULL` and not the null-*character* (which is something completely different even though they have similar names). And by the way, in your loop (the first version) `p` might never be `NULL` unless you're going way past the allocated memory and the pointer value overflows.

Comment: I do reserve sufficient space so that there will be null values before hitting overflow. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Suspect code wants `iptstat* ips=malloc(100000 * sizeof *ips);`  I question that "properly fills up iptstat structure" part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `p+=sz;` you increment p with `sz*sizeof(iptstat))`. You should just write `p++;` as the compiler knows the size of `iptstat`.

(See also comment by Joachim that `while(p != '\0')` should be `while(p->IP)`)